# Word for planning a visit to relative

Tags: choix-de-mot

> Je suis en train ____ ma visite à ma tante le mois prochain.

What is the best word if I want to say I'm planning/organizing my visit? Is it *d'organiser*, *de planifier*, or others?

Comment: *Planifier* seems fine. Or you could say **J'envisage...**

Comment: J'envisage de visiter ma tante le mois prochain.

Comment: English speakers are known to easily fall into the trap of doing this, but in many cases, the use of "en train de" to express the idea of "be doing" ought to be avoided in favour of the Indicative Present tense.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Could you please explain why *en train de* is not appropriate here?

Comment: Hi. The use of "en train de" sounds strange to me here, **unless** you really want to emphasise the idea of "**now**", "**at this very moment**".

Comment: @Ahalone-zee Thanks, I see. If I just say "Je planifie ma visite ...", then wouldn't there be no emphasis that I'm doing it *now*? (It isn't necessarily that I'm doing it *at this very moment*, but I'm in the process of doing it.) Or maybe I should add "Je planifie **en ce moment/maintenant** ma visite"?

Comment: Hi. Please note that it is completely fine to use "en train de" here if you really want to emphasise the NOW aspect of the ongoing process. Otherwise, I'd prefer to go with NB's suggestion and use "envisager" in the indicative present tense.

Comment: One of the most illuminating examples would be: "I'm trying to do" = "J'essaie de faire" rather than "Je suis en train d'essayer de faire".

Comment: May I suggest "**Je prévois** de visiter ma tante le mois prochain".

Comment: @Alone-zee *Être en train de* does not mean you are actually doing the action this very moment. The action can take place over a long period of time. "*Nous ne pouvons pas vous inviter en ce moment parce que nous sommes en train de refaire notre cuisine*", obviously when I write this I'm not actually painting or tiling the kitchen, and it will be done over a period of time while I'll be doing other things as well (sleeping, going out to work, eating, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

> Je suis en train d'organiser / de planifier ma visite à ma tante le mois prochain

it definitely means you already have made your decision to visit your aunt.  This rules out using *envisager* or *prévoir* as suggested in another answer. Both *envisager* and *prévoir* are used for an action you have not yet decided to accomplish.

*Organiser* and *planifier* both work here. But to me they do not exactly mean the same.

> Je suis en train de planifier ma visite à ma tante le mois prochain

means you are trying to fit the action in your general timetable. You might not have decided on the exact date(s) of your visit.

> Je suis en train d'organiser ma visite à ma tante le mois prochain.

means you most probably have decided on the date(s) of the visit and are actually attending to the various tasks that need to be done before you can undertake the visit (buying travel tickets, getting a present, looking for someone to mind the dog in your absence, etc.).

*Organiser* could be replaced by *préparer*, but *préparer* does not bring out the idea of things being as systematically thought out.

Answer (score 0):

Although both « envisager » and « prévoir » can be translated into "plan / be planning", I’d say they differ in one crucial respect:

> 1 : J’**envisage** de visiter ma tante le mois prochain.

Here, the speaker is just toying with the idea, planning it in his mind only, and probably not making any actual preparation for it yet. It remains to be seen whether she will actually carry out the plan.

> 2 : Je **prévois** de visiter ma tante le mois prochain.

Whereas with the use of « prévoir », the plan sounds more realistic: she not only envisions the possibility of visiting her aunt, but also she may well have already set some part of the preparation for the trip in motion – by booking a train ticket, clearing her schedule for that day etc.

Or, even if she has yet to go beyond comtemplating the idea just in her mind, she is more likely to realise the plan than « envisager » suggests.

---

The use of « planifier », on the other hand, presupposes that the plan is due to be carried out. The planning is no longer confined to the comtemplating aspect. I’d rather reserve « planifier » for talking about actually organising something – whether it be planning an assassination attempt, the remodeling of a house, an official visit, an extensive vacation etc.

Comment: Thanks. What about "Je planifie la visite ...", or "Je planifie de visiter ..." (if that's correct to say)?

Comment: Hi. I'd say so, though I'd much prefer to stick to the other verbs in this particular instance. On a side note, I tend to associate the verb « planifier » with the « planifier + noun » construction. Updated.

Comment: There's no problem with *je suis en train de*. If you use only *envisager* or *prévoir* you leave out the fact that OP is asking for *organiser* or *planifier* to show the  organising side.